# Dimension versus codimension in the definition of smoothness for an affine variety in Wikipedia

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety#Singular_points_and_tangent_space) it states (paraphrased):

> Let $V$ be an affine variety defined by the polynomials $f_{1},\dots ,f_{r}\in k[x_{1},\dots ,x_{n}]$ and $a=(a_{1},\dots ,a_{n})$ be a point of $V$.
> Let $J_V(a)$ be the Jacobian matrix  of $V$.
> The point a is regular if the rank of $J_V(a)$ equals the dimension of $V$, and singular otherwise.

This is not making too much sense to me... Should be the codimension of $V$?
Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: firs this does not define dimension of $V$,it define smoothness. secondly yes it should be codimension.

Comment: that's a good point thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it should be codimension instead of dimension. One can think about the linear subvariety $V(x_1,\cdots,x_r)\subset\Bbb A^n$: this has dimension $n-r$ and the Jacobian is of rank $r$. I've corrected this issue on the Wikipedia page by changing "dimension" to "codimension".